# How to put LineBreak in dynamically created Label in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013, label, wpf-controls

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate and have Framework 4.5.

I am new to WPF and I am creating the label **dynamically** I mean in back end and I want to give the **break line** in given text to **Label**.

The code I have written is:

```
Label lblName = new Label();
lblName.Content = "FirstName LastName";
```

here I want to give break line between FirstName and LastName so my output will come like.

FirstName

LastName

but not like

FirstName LastName

So how to put in between FirstName and LastName a breakline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try as follows,

```
Label lblName = new Label(); 
lblName.Content = "FirstName" + Environment.NewLine + "LastName";
```

Comment: Yes that's what I want Arun Selva Kumar Appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to do that with a single label.  Add a second label.

Comment: Yes Jeff Matthews you are right but I have to do this so as requirement. No problem I just have to use to display the info not use label for further.